# Show div elements in one row

Tags: html, css

i've written some divs and i want to show some images in one row in a div but images appear in different rows ! thank you.

```
<body>
<div class="header"> Site Header <br />
<p> به وب سایت من خوش آمدید</p>
</div>
<div class="left_menu"> Left Menu <br />
<marquee>
<a href="http://bmi.ir">بانک ملی ایران</a><br />
<a href="http://softgozar.com">سافت گذر</a><br />
</marquee>
 </div>
<div class="main_menu"> Main Menu <br />
<div>
<img src="porteghal-logo.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
<p> پرتقال </p>
</div>
<div>
<img src="1551874344_M7mS5-600x363.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
<p> هندوانه </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> Site Footer </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: You should include the relevant code. We don't know what styling your are doing just by class names. Divs by default cause line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add display:inline-block; to each div that contains image so they would be inlined.

```html
<body>
<div class="header"> Site Header <br />
<p> به وب سایت من خوش آمدید</p>
</div>
<div class="left_menu"> Left Menu <br />
<marquee>
<a href="http://bmi.ir">بانک ملی ایران</a><br />
<a href="http://softgozar.com">سافت گذر</a><br />
</marquee>
 </div>
<div class="main_menu"> Main Menu <br />
<div style="display:inline-block;">
<img src="porteghal-logo.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
<p> پرتقال </p>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
<img src="1551874344_M7mS5-600x363.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
<p> هندوانه </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> Site Footer </div>
</body>
```